# Simple Question Regarding 'CPLEX: Row index 0 out of range'

Tags: cplex

I'm **extremely** new to CPLEX. I'm trying to replicate some code I found online, and I've gotten the following error:

```
p.variables.add(obj = obj, lb = lb, ub = ub, columns=cols, types=types)

CPLEX Error  1203: Row index 0 out of range.
```

I have absolutely no idea where this is coming from. I checked the length of all the variables - obj, lb, ub, cols, types, and they are all the same, so the problem doesn't have to do with differing lengths. However, I can't tell exactly where the mistake is coming from!

Comment: There may be many reasons for this error. Providing a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help others find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to populate the model by column. My guess is that you haven't added the linear constraints to the model yet (a prerequisite). For example, the following program reproduces your problem:

```
import cplex                                                                    
p = cplex.Cplex()                                                               
# Uncomment this line to fix the problem:                                       
#p.linear_constraints.add(names=['c1', 'c2', 'c3'])                             
p.variables.add(columns=[[[0, 1, 2], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]])                         
p.write("prob.lp")
```

This can be fixed by uncommenting the line that adds the linear constraints first. You should take a look at the examples that are shipped with CPLEX to see how things are done (e.g., `lpex1.py`, `mipex1.py`, etc.).